# What is mean by passing the enum array?

Tags: c++, c

can we pass enum as an array or pointer. I heard this type of question somewhere in internet. so I want to check what is that mean. how can we do that? example?

Comment: Do you mean an array of enum values? Or a pointer to an value? If so, it's no different to an array of or pointer to regular integer values.

Comment: yes, array of enum value. how can we pass to function?

Comment: Pass it like any other array, but the length must be known to the function or the array must contain a terminating value (`ENUM_INVALID` for example).

Comment: if you can write some short of code, that we could help me to understand more about this, thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible do the same thing without creating memory in main as enum colour estonia[] = {BLUE, BLACK, WHITE};

Comment: What do you mean, it is possible?

Comment: @kapilddit: no, it's not possible. You can only use initialiser lists like `{1, 2, 3}` or `{BLUE, BLACK, WHITE}` when initialising a variable. By the way, what's with unaccepting my answer? Has it somehow become less satisfactory with respect to your question?

Comment: No Its perfect and 100% satisfactory..  I am doing initialization part in constructor (c++), so every time I need not to deal with memory.. I have multiple array like this.. {BLUE, BLACK, WHITE} with different color. So should I make common array or multiple array with differnt options.. I want to do this in generic and optimized way. Thanks @len

Comment: @kapilddit: I'm afraid there's no easy answer. You should take the path that has the least code duplication and is the easiest for you to maintain; they're likely all equally optimal from a (realistic) speed perspective.

Comment: @Len thanks for your contribution in solving my problem. I will choose the path with least duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like any other array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum colour {
    WHITE,
    RED,
    ORANGE,
    YELLOW,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    INDIGO,
    VIOLET,
    BLACK
};

char *colour_names[] = {
    "WHITE",
    "RED",
    "ORANGE",
    "YELLOW",
    "GREEN",
    "BLUE",
    "INDIGO",
    "VIOLET",
    "BLACK"
};

void show_colours(enum colour colours[], int count) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf("%s ", colour_names[(int)colours[i]]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    enum colour estonia[] = {BLUE, BLACK, WHITE};
    show_colours(estonia, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
BLUE BLACK WHITE
```

Comment: enum colour estonia[] = {BLUE, BLACK, WHITE}; what does this statement do? redefine?

Comment: @kapilddit That declares an array of three `enum colour`s, initialised with `BLUE`, `BLACK` and `WHITE` (the colours of Estonia's flag).

Comment: @kapilddit It's just like `int x[] = {1, 2}`, which declares an array of two `int`s with said values. You could equivalently declare such an array in the heap with: `int *x = malloc(sizeof(*x) * 2); x[0] = 1; x[1] = 2;` Note that these carry no information about their own length.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. I mean, if you have

```
typedef enum {
    ALFA,
    BRAVO,
    CHARLIE,
    DELTA
} Alphabet;
```

there's no way you can pass that information, as is, to a function.

What you CAN do is, to declare an array of integers and *assign* to that array the values of Alphabet:

Alphabet ab[26] = { ALFA, BRAVO, CHARLIE, ... }

At that point you will be able to pass "ab" as you would any other pointer.